# How to detect iOS and show banner once in pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mobile-safari, detection

This script works to show a banner on all platforms, but I would like it to show only when it detects iOS devices.

<---- Good Script------->

```
const cookieBanner = document.querySelector(".cookie-banner");
const cookieButton = document.querySelector(".cookie-btn");

cookieButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  cookieBanner.classList.remove("active");
  localStorage.setItem("cookieBannerDisplayed", "true");
});

setTimeout(() => {

  
  if (!localStorage.getItem("cookieBannerDisplayed")) {
    cookieBanner.classList.add("active");
  }
}, 2000);
```

I tried doing this below but it didn't work. Instead, it completely no longer works on any platform; not on Safari iOS, Safari, Chrome nor Firefox.

<---- Bad Script------->

```
const cookieBanner = document.querySelector(".cookie-banner");
const cookieButton = document.querySelector(".cookie-btn");
var t = window.navigator.userAgent,
    a = window.navigator.platform;

cookieButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  cookieBanner.classList.remove("active");
  localStorage.setItem("cookieBannerDisplayed", "true");
});

setTimeout(() => {

  
  if (!localStorage.getItem("cookieBannerDisplayed")) &&  if (!["iPhone", "iPad", "iPod"].indexOf(a)) {
    cookieBanner.classList.add("active");
  }
}, 2000);
```

Edit: I'm including the CSS code that it 'active'ates.

What this does is show the banner sliding into the users view:

```
.cookie-banner{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color:#282828;
    opacity: 0.90;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: -100%;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: start;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 400;
    box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) 0px -1px 0px 0px;
    padding: 1rem 1.25rem 1rem 18px;
    transition: 400ms;
}






.cookie-banner a{
     color: #f5f6fa;
     text-decoration: underline;

}
.cookie-btn {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    padding: .2rem 1rem;
    font-size: .875rem;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.cookie-banner.active {
    top: 0;

}
```

Below is the main page that the user is looking at basically the body is normally filled with article words.
On the main page I have this

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/ios-banner.css">
</head>



<body>


div class="cookie-banner">
  <p> We use cookies to provide you with the best experience on our site. <a href="https://somewebsitehere.website/privacy.php">Learn More</a>  </p>
<button class="cookie-btn">Okay</button>
</div>


 <script src="assets/js/ios-banner.js"></script>

</body>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what in the world should be `if (!localStorage.getItem("cookieBannerDisplayed")) &&  if (!["iPhone", "iPad", "iPod"].indexOf(a))`?

Comment: I edited the posts to give the complete picture of what works well to show a banner if the user has not already clicked "okay" but when I add the && second condition nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was you had bad logic in your set timeout callback, and you have not got a proper opening tag to your banner div in the html you list.

Also in general try to use good naming practices instead of variable names like 't' and 'a' as it will make your code hard to read and therefore hard to understand.

Here is what worked for me:

The CSS (unchanged)

```
.cookie-banner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #282828;
  opacity: 0.90;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) 0px -1px 0px 0px;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem 1rem 18px;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.cookie-banner a {
  color: #f5f6fa;
  text-decoration: underline;

}

.cookie-btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  padding: .2rem 1rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.cookie-banner.active {
  top: 0;

}
```

The HTML, used ids for selectors and fixed the opening div tag error

```
<div id="cookie-banner-id" class="cookie-banner">
  <p>
    We use cookies to provide you with the best experience on our site.
    <a href="https://somewebsitehere.website/privacy.php">
      Learn More
    </a>
  </p>
  <button id="cookie-btn-id" class="cookie-btn">Okay</button>
</div>
```

The JS

```
const cookieBanner = document.getElementById("cookie-banner-id");
const cookieButton = document.getElementById("cookie-btn-id");
const userAgentValue = navigator.userAgent;
let cookieBannerDisplayed = false;
let activeClassAdded = false; // so we only add active once

cookieButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  cookieBanner.classList.remove("active");
  localStorage.setItem("cookieBannerDisplayed", true);
});

setTimeout(() => {
  if (!localStorage.getItem("cookieBannerDisplayed")){
    ["iPhone", "iPad", "iPod"].forEach((targetBrowserName) => {
        if (userAgentValue.includes(targetBrowserName) && !activeClassAdded) {
        cookieBanner.classList.add("active");
          activeClassAdded = true;
      }
    });
  } 
}, 2000);
```

When testing you may need to clear local storage for each test run, else switch out the local storage for a local variable.

Comment: This absolutely worked. After coming back to my code I also found fixes. for the js part if I removed the second word "if"  and enclosed both conditions in an extra pair of parenthesis it also worked. thank you!